# Custom taxonomy not appearing in menu administration panel

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization

I am unable to see custom taxonomy box in the wordpress new menu system. I can see the post types but custom taxonomies are not available. I saw the screen options aswell custom taxonomies are not listed there. I am using more taxonomy plugin to create taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad it was of use to you askkirati, I commented the code in order to make it easy to see where the plugin needs to be fixed, it really wasn't a big change and to be honest I don't know why it wasn't included.

Answer (score 4):

In the upper right-hand area of the screen you will see a little tab labeled "Screen Options". You will want to click on it and make sure that the taxonomy's name is checked.

Comment: I already stated in my question i checked that but there is no custom taxonomy listed there with checkbox.

Comment: Opps, sorry about that. I've tried out the "More" plugin that you mentioned and it does not really register the taxonomies properly. I user was using it in conjunction with one of my plugins and was having issues. I did a through test of the "More" plugin and the errors were arising from it. I can give you code to register the taxonomy if you want. Just post the requirements.